# How to create Apple Keynote style Picture in Picture video

Tags: video, editing, video-editor

I want to take two video sources:

- A screencast of a PowerPoint presentation
- A camcorder AVCHD recording of the presenter and the conference room

..and create a video in the style of Apple's Keynote videos. See here for exactly what I'm looking for:

http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/06/12/apple-wwdc-video.jpg

The video feed of the PowerPoint itself would take up the majority of the screen and the video recording of the room/speaker would take up another, smaller, separate area of the screen.

I'd appreciate any advice on:

- What software can create this dual video effect?
- What method/software would you recommend for creating the screencast?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any fairly basic video editing package should be able to closely emulate the look.  You just have to be able to distort the video to make it fit the shape that looks like it is 3d and then size and position the speaker's video appropriately.  I'd personally probably do it in After Effects with a 3d layer for simplicity, but most far cheaper consumer video editing packages should be able to do basic deformations to get the same look.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a software package, called Keynote. Apple uses a version of it to make those presentations you see.

You would need to capture the camera footage to your computer, then you could embed the clip into a presentation easily. The workflow would be: import powerpoint, embed captured video, then export presentation as Quicktime movie with streaming enabled.